# Kibana UI isn't load in browser

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, elk

I installed Kibana and Elasticsearch on cent os. My VM is in GCP and created firewall to expose 5601,5602,9200 and 9300 port for outside and also open firewalld ports also.
services is also running.
[image]

[image]

when i check ports using netstat command i can see port is also listing.

*Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5601          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1591/node
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1105/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1269/master
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      2273/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      2273/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN      2273/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1105/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1269/master*

when i inspect the browser i can see this is header section.

*Request URL: http://X.X.X.X:5601/
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36*

and this is response section.
[image]

Browser is chrome and also updated.
Can i know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
Change the below line in "/etc/kibana/kibana.yml" file.

server.host: "localhost" => server.host: "0.0.0.0"

Comment: add proper blockquote while mentioning file path etc